# OnItemClickListener not working but OnItemLongClickListener is working on GridView

Tags: android, gridview, onitemclicklistener

I am having a problem with a clickListener on my gridview. The LongClickListener works without issue. But I cannot seem to get any response from the click Listener.

My code is below.

Im confused as to why the long click works but not the normal click,

Any pointers would be appreciated

Thanks

```
final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
gridView.setNumColumns(numOfColumns);
gridView.getLayoutParams().width = (CELL_WIDTH * numOfColumns);
gridView.getLayoutParams().height = (CELL_WIDTH * numOfRows);

....

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Log.d("ABCD", "Position Single Click is " + position);
            // Ideally in here I want to put to open a soft keyboard for the user to enter a value
            // InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            // imm.showSoftInput(gridView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
        }
    });

 gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          Log.d("ABCD", "Position Long Click is " + position);
          return true;
      }
 });
```

grid_view is

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
           android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/my_grid_view"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:clickable="true"/>   <<--- I WANT THIS TO GET THE CLICK
    <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/listId"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

GridCell in the grid view is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:padding="0dp" android:layout_margin="0dp"
           android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
   >

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:textSize="10px"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        >
</TextView>

<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@+id/celllabel"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:paddingRight="0dp"
          android:paddingTop="0dp"
          android:paddingBottom="0dp"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"
          android:focusable="false"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
          android:clickable="false"
          android:cursorVisible="false">
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The adapter class has a getView and is as below

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    MyObject obj = myObjects.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);

        String textColour = "#000000";
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font color='%s'>%s</font>", textColour, obj.getValue())));

        TextView superScriptTv = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_number);
        if (obj.getNumber() > 0) {
            superScriptTv.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font>%s</font>", cell.getNumber())));
        }


    } else {
        gridView = convertView;
    }

    gridView.setBackgroundColor(obj.getBackgroundColour());

    return gridView;
}
```

**EDIT**
Really banging my head against a wall here now :)
Im updating the code sample so have more data. Ive noticed that in my adapter if I do not set the text on the textview with ID = R.id.grid_item_number then it works. As soon as I set text on it then I lose the click listener.

The linked question/answer doesnt help from what I can see. Can anyone help with my stupidity?

**EDIT**
Adapter code has been added.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this question/answer out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982472/gridview-onitemclicklistener-never-gets-invoked

Comment: Can you please post complete xml code for GridCell ?

Comment: can you share your code inside adapter

Comment: Hi @ankitaggarwal Ive just added the getView from the adapter class. If you require more code please let me know. Thanks for looking

Comment: Are you using *both* at once? Isn't the onClickListener working even when you remove the onLongClickListener?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with the `EditText` inside the `row_cell`. When you click on the item, it takes focus and prevents the whole item to be clickable again. As you noticed, only long click works.
[Here you have a similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25519896/click-gridview-item-and-editext-gets-focus)

To resolve that issue I would move your `OnItemClickListeners` from the Activity / Fragment to your `GridViewAdapter`, so instead of:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                            int position, long id) {
        Log.d("ABCD", "Position Single Click is " + position);
        // Ideally in here I want to put to open a soft keyboard for the user to enter a value
        // InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        // imm.showSoftInput(gridView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    }
});

gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      Log.d("ABCD", "Position Long Click is " + position);
      return true;
  }
});
```

I would do something like that:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridViewItem;

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridViewItem = new View(mContext);
        gridViewItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)gridViewItem.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_number);
        textView.setText(mValues[position]);

        EditText editText = (EditText)gridViewItem.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);



    } else {
        gridViewItem = (View) convertView;
    }

    gridViewItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("GRID", "onClick: " );
        }
    });

    gridViewItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.e("GRID", "onLongClick: " );
            return true;
        }
    });

    return gridViewItem;

}
```

It will prevent this strange behaviour you are struggling right now.

For the sake of that example please find my code below:

MainActivity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="io.github.mmbs.gridviewcheck.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true">

</GridView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Grid cell layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="TEXTVIEW">
</TextView>

<EditText
          android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="0dp"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"
          android:cursorVisible="false"
          android:layout_below="@id/grid_item_number"
          android:text="EDITTEXT">
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please take into consideration, that I removed all layouts attributes responsible for `focusability`.

MyGridAdapter:

```
public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private final String[] mValues;

public MyGridViewAdapter(String[] values, Context context) {
    mValues = values;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridViewItem;

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridViewItem = new View(mContext);
        gridViewItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)gridViewItem.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_number);
        textView.setText(mValues[position]);

        EditText editText = (EditText)gridViewItem.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);



    } else {
        gridViewItem = (View) convertView;
    }

    gridViewItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("GRID", "onClick: " );
        }
    });

    gridViewItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.e("GRID", "onLongClick: " );
            return true;
        }
    });

    return gridViewItem;

}
}
```

If you like, I can also share this code on github, so you will have a fully operational example.

The second option is to leave your implementation as it is and do hacks when the `EditText` is focusable and enabled. Here you have related topics:

1. [Android: Force EditText to remove focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus)
2. [ListView items focus behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977436/listview-items-focus-behaviour)
3. [Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)
4. [Android: Force EditText to remove focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056734/android-force-edittext-to-remove-focus)

What is more, please take into account [that answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8208567/2065587)

> Do not use clickable objects in the grid. In that case Android cannot handle the click event of GridView.
>
> Instead, use something to show a similar user interface view. Then handle that object's click actions.
>
> Don't: put Button in the GridView to perform some click actions.
>
> Do: put an ImageView instead of ImageButton and handle ImageView's click events.

Edit: Please find a [link to the project on my Github](https://github.com/mmBs/GridViewCheck).

Comment: thank @mmBs for the very comprehensive answer! Will check this over the next day or so.

Comment: Im checking this tonight @mmBs.

Comment: Hi @mmBs. It doesnt seem to work and I think this is because the textView/EditText part are underneath each other. I see  android:layout_below="@id/grid_item_number". For my code they are actually on top of each other. I think you've defintely got me closer but will continue a bit more. It seems that when I click on the TextView part then I get the call but when I click on the EditText part it isnt coming through

Comment: and I may be asking for more now ;) but ideally I want to open a keyboard on the click. I have tried to replace the debug code with opening keyboard code but that doesnt work either. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Hi @RNJ, the thing is that it is really hard to recreate / reproduce your issue without having all code. That was the reason I created my own project and started to experiment. You wrote that your `TextView` and `EditText` are on top of each other., so maybe that is the case. Can you, for instance, change your `grid_cell` layout and experiment a little bit? What is more, you did not add `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes to the `RelativeLayout` of your `grid_cell`. Btw, I think you can also play with `RecyclerView` and replace your `GridView` and `ListView` as well :)

Comment: I will also think about your issue in the morning ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help @mmBs. can you put the code on GitHub? I'd like to compare what you have with what I have. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RNJ, please find the link to the repo [here](https://github.com/mmBs/GridViewCheck)

Answer (score 3):

use `gridView.setOnItemClickListener(.....)` **and** to your root view add below line

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

> The ViewGroup will block its descendants from receiving focus.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in your GridCell -->TextView

Answer (score 1):

Try using recycler view if you are comfortable with it.

It doesn't gives any such problem in addition to this it has its own advantages.

Follow the [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) for complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any focus-able view in you your row layout, then the onItemClickListener will not be called. For this problem you need to customize your getView code and set onClickListener() on convertView and pass the callback to activity using the Interface. I have updated the code of your Adapter as below. Now you need to implement the GridViewItemClickListener on your activity  and pass the instance while creating the Adapter instance.

```
 public class MyGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private final String[] mValues;
private GridViewItemClickListener mListener;

public MyGridViewAdapter(String[] values, Context context,GridViewItemClickListener listener ) {
    mValues = values;
    mContext = context; 
    mListener = listener;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridViewItem;

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridViewItem = new View(mContext);
        gridViewItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)gridViewItem.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_number);
        textView.setText(mValues[position]);

        EditText editText = (EditText)gridViewItem.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);



    } else {
        gridViewItem = (View) convertView;
    }



    gridViewItem.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.e("GRID", "onLongClick: " );
            return true;
        }
    });
//Add an OnclickListener here
   gridViewItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if(mListener != null){
           mListener.onGridItemClick(v, position);
           }
        }
    });

    return gridViewItem;

}

public interface GridViewItemClickListener{
   void onGridItemClick(View v, int index);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how can the click listener work if you set the root element in GridCell.java as non-clickable ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:padding="0dp" android:layout_margin="0dp"
           android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Remove those lines from each of your components in the GridCell.java

```
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

I don't think this is required for GridView, but sometimes for RecyclerView it is required to have android:clickable="true" on the root componenent of GridCell.java

Answer (score 1):

You can user click listeners inside the adapter it will work ,it should work like this

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

```
    View gridView;

    MyObject obj = myObjects.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_cell, null);

        String textColour = "#000000";
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font color='%s'>%s</font>", textColour, obj.getValue())));

        TextView superScriptTv = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_number);
        superScriptTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // here you can use every item of grid acc to position
            }
        });
        if (obj.getNumber() > 0) {
            superScriptTv.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.format("<font>%s</font>", cell.getNumber())));
        }


    } else {
        gridView = convertView;
    }

    gridView.setBackgroundColor(obj.getBackgroundColour());

    return gridView;
}
```